# org mode open link in browser directly

Tags: org-mode, org-link, hyperlinks

Suppose, we have a link `[[https://www.google.com/][Google]]`. When I put the cursor at the link and run `org-open-at-point`, instead of opening https://www.google.com/ in browser it downloads the page to `/var/tmp` and opens the file in browser: file:///var/tmp/kdecache-user/krun/20635_0_. All the css and js are broken of course.

Can I make it open the direct link in browser? Or maybe, it's not Emacs, but KDE.

Comment: What's the "it" that downloads the page to `/var/tmp`?

Comment: What happens if you say `ESC ESC : (browse-url "https://www.google.com/") RET`?

Comment: @NickD "it" is the html page of google. It is downloaded into a file and then opened in Firefox.

Comment: @NickD When I execute the command, I get the same thing: it is downloaded into a file and the file is opened in Firefox.

Comment: @NickD Does it work correctly on your system?

Comment: Yes, it does. You need to check `browse-url` (that's what `org-open-at-point` uses under the covers). What is the value of `browse-url-browser-function`? Do `C-h v browse-url-browser-function` - it's a variable.

Comment: @NickD The value is `browse-url-default-browser`.

Comment: Assuming you want FF as your default browser, try adding this to your init file: `(setq browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-firefox)`, restart emacs and see if that works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122845/discussion-between-nickd-and-user4035).

Comment: @NickD Thank you, setting the variable to firefox worked. Maybe, KDE had some strange default browser that downloaded the page. Can you add an answer so I could accept it?

Comment: Added an answer: I hope the detail is helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This answer is meant as a tutorial introduction to how one would debug problems like the OP's, so it is more detailed than the "answer" which is just the setting
of `browse-url-browser-function` below. But I have always found answers of the sort "Do `this` - problem solved" unsatisfactory: I like to understand what's going on. YMMV, in which case skip the long-winded explanations.]

`org-open-at-point` calls `org-link-open` which uses the variable `org-link-parameters` to look up the `:follow` property for the type of the link. In this case the type is `https` and the `:follow` property turns out to be an anonymous function that is set when the file `ol.el[c]` (l.1349 in my version of the file) is loaded:

```el
...
;;;; "http", "https", "mailto", "ftp", and "news" link types
(dolist (scheme '("ftp" "http" "https" "mailto" "news"))
  (org-link-set-parameters scheme
               :follow
               (lambda (url arg)
                 (browse-url (concat scheme ":" url) arg))))
...
```

The upshot is that this anonymous (`lambda`) function calls `browse-url`. It is unlikely that the problem as described is caused by any of the above, so we concentrate on `browse-url`.

Reading the doc string of `browse-url` (`C-h f browse-url`) uncovers the fact that it calls the function that is specified as the value of the variable `browse-url-browser-function`. After prodding the OP with a question, we find out that the OP's setting of that variable was `browse-url-default-browser`. Unfortunately for debugging purposes (*remote* debugging purposes, no less), that function pokes around all over the place until it finds something that it can use and then calls that something. So at that point, it was more expedient to suggest that the OP bypass that and set the `browse-url-browser-function` variable directly to the function corresponding to the desired browser:

```el
(setq browse-url-browser-function #'browse-url-firefox)
```

Setting that in the init file did the trick for the OP. Other "direct to external browser" function available include `browse-url-chrome` and `browse-url-mozilla`.

The only remaining mystery is why the default browser function did what the OP described. From the description, it seems that the culprit is `browse-url-kde`. I have no way to test that, but a KDE user can confirm (or refute) that claim by evaluating the following (e.g. in the `*scratch*` buffer - paste the expression and type `C-j` after the closing paren):

```el
(browse-url-kde "https://www.google.com")
```

If that does what the OP describes, it's arguably a bug in the `browse-url-kde` function and should probably be reported (`M-x report-emacs-bug`).

Comment: What an excellent answer, thank you!

Comment: Glad you liked it! It's been a while but I think it was fun to write up as well :-)

Comment: It's been a year, but I'm wondering if you might be able to recommend a method add another browser? There is no `#'browse-url-librewolf` function. I assume that it's not as simple as copying `defun browse-url-firefox` to your config.el and changing `firefox` to `librewolf`?

Comment: It pretty much is: you'll also have to define a `browse-url-librowolf-program` variable and a `browse-url-librewolf-arguments` variable in analogy with the corresponding `firefox` variables - but that should be it. Besides, if you try it and it doesn't work, you know where to ask :-)

Comment: Very excellent answer, Nick! It's appreciated!